# How to show div with the help of HyperLinked Field in a grid

Tags: asp.net

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdAdslCompanyAdvisers" Width="100%" HeaderStyle-BackColor="ActiveCaption"
                            HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="FormTableContainer"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" ForeColor="Black" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Days">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Name" DataTextField="Name" DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="#MyDiv " />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>

  <div id ="MyDiv"></div>
```

I need to show a div section(ClientDetail wil show in this div) as per the selected Client Name.I know DataNavigateUrlFormatString will use for redirecting to destination page. But I need show Div section on same opage. And If there is other option , then plz Kindly suggest.

Comment: Can you use updatepanel for partial update?

Comment: please refer this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView-DetailsView-Master-Detail-Example-Display-selected-GridView-Row-in-DetailsView-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Can you elaborate your view, As If I click on ClientName then I need to pass ClientId to show detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your GridView code as below , add `TemplateColumn`, add `OnRowCommand="grdAdslCompanyAdvisers_RowCommand"`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="grdAdslCompanyAdvisers" Width="100%" HeaderStyle-BackColor="ActiveCaption"
                        HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="FormTableContainer"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ForeColor="Black" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowCommand="grdAdslCompanyAdvisers_RowCommand">
                        <Columns>                               
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btn" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>'' CommandName="View" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>                                                                                                
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                  <div id ="MyDiv">
                      <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" />
                  </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In code behind

```
protected void grdAdslCompanyAdvisers_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "View") {
            //Get Command Argument
            e.CommandArgument.ToString(); // get ID and display details by adding some Label/Gridview details in MyDiv                
        }
    }
```